# Common root in polynomial equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots

The value of $\frac {a}{b}$ so that the equations $ax^2+2bx+a =0$  and  $x^3-2x^2+2x-1 =0$  have exactly one root in common is:

$1)\ 0$

$2)\ 1$

$3)\ -1$

$4)\ 2$

Comment: The cubic equation, $x^3- 2x^2+ 2x- 1= 0$ has the obvious solution x= 1.  Dividing by x- 1 leaves the quadratic $x^2- x+ 1= 0$ which, by the quadratic formula, has roots $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: is your Problem solved now?

Comment: @DrSonnhardGraubner You might want to check the roots of that quadratic.  Should be $6^{th}$ roots of unity.

Answer (score 3):

First case :$a/b=0$. then
the first equation has zero as unique root. but zero is not a root of the second equation.

Second case : $a/b=1$. then the first equation has $-1$ as unique root.but $-1$ is not a root of the second.

Third case : $a/b=-1$. then the first equation has $1$ as unique root which is also a root of the second.

Fourth case :$a/b=2$. in this case, the first equation has no real root.

thus $a/b=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $ax^2+2bx+a=0$ and $x^3−2x^2+2x−1=0$

We can say that \begin{align}ax^2+2bx+a&=a(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)\\
x^2+\frac {2a}bx+1&=x^2+(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta\end{align}

We can then equate coefficients, to find that \begin{align}\frac{2b}a&=\alpha+\beta\\
1&=\alpha\beta\end{align}

So, we can see that \begin{align}\frac ba &= \frac{\alpha+\beta}2\\
&=\frac{\alpha+\frac 1\alpha}2\end{align} where $\alpha$ is the shared root

We can then factorise $x^3-2x^2+2x-1=(x-1)(x^2-x+1)$

The common root must be $x=1$ as having $ax^2+2bx+a=x^2-x+1$ would give us two common roots*

We can therefore see that \begin{align}\frac ba &= \frac{-1+\frac{1}{-1}}2\\
&=\frac{-2}2\\
&=-1\end{align}

---

*The equation $x^2-x+1$ has the roots $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt2}{2}$. If the first equation shares one root, then it must share the other, due to the fact that complex roots come in these such pairs

Answer (score 1):

Solve the cubic equation:
$$x^3-2x^2+2x-1 =0 \Rightarrow (x^3-1)-(2x^2-2x)=0 \Rightarrow$$
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)-2x(x-1)=0\Rightarrow$$
$$(x-1)(x^2-x+1)=0 \Rightarrow x=1.$$

Substitute this root into the quadratic equation:

$$a+2b+a=0 \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}=-1.$$